# Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _this.searchElementRef is undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have used google place api following [this](http://www.17educations.com/angularjs-2/google-map-api-angular-2-typescript/)

but i am getting this error below

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
```

-html file

```
 <div class="form-group" [formGroup]="myGroup">
    <input placeholder="search for location" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="off" type="text" class="form-control" #search formControlName="searchControl">
 </div>
```

-typescript file:

```
  @ViewChild("search") searchElementRef: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {console.log(this.searchElementRef)}
```

I want to use this.searchElementRef.nativeElement.

Comment: Are you using ngIf somewhere?

Comment: yes in html file i have used it.

Comment: Now  i have removed ngif from everywhere in html file.still getting same error

Comment: Please reproduce this issue on stackblitz. I don't know what you're doing behind the code above

Comment: Now issue solved. it was offcurse cause of ngif thanx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

avoid using *ngIf and handle this case by display: none or hidden, this is probably due to if the child is defined as a nested child of a ngIf element ngAfterViewInit() is run blindly.checking if child load in dom or not.
have a look at this [GitHub](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid/issues/411) issue.

Comment: how can i check if child load in dom or not?

Comment: Now issue solved,it was because of ngif.thanx for help

Comment: that's great happy to help. happy coding